# EXCEL VBA when converting double<0 to time gets #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I have this workbook, with 2 worksheets including a column with times each, I need to sync the times - by the first cell in each time column, I'm doing it by finding the time gap and adding/subtracting the amount of time from the 2nd sheet. looks like this:

```
Dim somethingz As Double
Dim SanTime As Date, PhTime As Date

SanTime = Worksheets("Sanity").Cells(2, "B").Value
PhTime = Worksheets("PH").Cells(2, "B").Value

For i = 2 To phRowN

            somethingz = Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value - dblDuration
            Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value = Application.Text(somethingz, "[hh]:mm:ss")
       Next i
    Else
        dblDuration = PhTime - SanTime
        For i = 2 To phRowN

            somethingz = Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value - dblDuration

            If (somethingz < 0) Then
                somethingz = something + twentyfour
            End If

            Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value = Application.Text(somethingz, "[hh]:mm:ss")

       Next i
    End If
```

Now, this works great until I get `somethingz<0` for example if time gap is 01:30:00 in favor of first sheet and the time in second one is 00:05:00 (should be adjusted to 22:35:00) it gets #VALUE!

Note that until 23:59:00 it will work well, and after 01:31:00 it also works.

Tried to add 24:00:00 to the "negative" time with no success.

Comment: For the benefit of both answerers and future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it at least _helpful_, please _up-vote_ it by clicking the up-arrow icon. To show extra appreciation for an answer you accept, you may up-vote it in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
If dblDuration < Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value Then
    dblDuration = dblDuration +1
End if
somethingz = Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value - dblDuration
Worksheets("PH").Cells(i, "B").Value = Application.Text(somethingz, "[hh]:mm:ss")
```